# Facebook android login crashing app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm working on a third party Facebook Android app. I've got the code working well so far but my app crashes when I add the Facebook login code below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;

    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView userNameView;



    private final List<String> permissions;

    public MainFragment() {
        permissions = Arrays.asList("user_status", "read_stream", "friends_about_me", "friends_work_history", "friends_activities",
                "friends_birthday", "user_checkins", "friends_checkins", "user_education_history", "friends_education_history", "user_events",
                "friends_events", "user_groups", "friends_groups", "user_hometown", "friends_hometown", "user_interests", "friends_interests",
                "user_likes", "friends_likes", "user_notes", "friends_notes", "user_online_presence", "friends_online_presence", "user_interests",
                "friends_interests", "user_likes", "friends_likes", "user_notes", "friends_notes", "user_online_presence", "friends_online_presence",
                "user_religion_politics", "friends_religion_politics", "user_status", "friends_status", "user_subscriptions",
                "friends_subscriptions", "user_videos", "friends_videos", "user_website", "friends_website", "user_work_history",
                "friends_work_history", "read_friendlists", "read_mailbox", "read_requests", "read_stream", "xmpp_login", "email", "user_location",
                "user_photos", "friends_photos");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
        // Make an API call to get user data and define a 
        // new callback to handle the response.
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // If the response is successful
                // Check for an open session
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                    // Get the user's data
                    makeMeRequest(session);
                }

                    if (user != null) {
                        // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                        // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                        profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                        // Set the Textview's text to the user's name.
                        userNameView.setText(user.getName());
                    }
                    {
                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    // Handle errors, will do so later.
                }
            }
        }});
        request.executeAsync();
    } 

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);


        // Find the user's profile picture custom view
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.sidebar_profile_picture);
        profilePictureView.setCropped(true);
        // Find the user's name view
        userNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sidebar_profile_name);
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);

        return view;
    }




    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }


    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");


            getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }}
```

Is there anyone that can help me figure out what is causing the app to crash?

Here is my main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#324D82" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/splash_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:text="FrontPage for Facebook" />
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" > 
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:text="Version 1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>


   <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my sidebar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/sidebar_profile_height"
    android:id="@+id/sidebar_profile"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/sidebar_profile_cover"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/test_image1" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pref_user_profile"/>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_profile_selector"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="6.0dip">

            <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
                android:id="@+id/sidebar_profile_picture"
                android:src="@drawable/test_profile_pic"
                android:layout_width="42.0dip"
                android:layout_height="42.0dip"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/pref_user_profile"
                android:padding="2.0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_picture_border"
                facebook:preset_size="small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sidebar_profile_name" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:paddingTop="8.0dip"
                android:text="@string/test_title_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does the stacktrace say? Can you post that.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse ADT then just open LogCat window to see logs. You can see errors here also. If LogCat window is not available then just go to Window > Show View menu, and click on LogCat or click on Others option. Run your project and see LogCat, find the errors, copy then and post here.

Comment: Please post xml code of layout also.

Comment: Couldn't get the LogCat. I have added the layouts.